# Не работает canvas.toDataUrl() для холстов слишком большого размера

Tags: javascript, ios, html5, canvas

При сохранении холста, методом toDataUrl, а затем преобразованием его в изображение на сервере - бывает сохраняется пустое изображение. 
Это случается на iphone 6,7, а так же недавно заметил что и на Meizu MX4 PRO та же проблема.
На ios, читал что стоит ограничение в пикселях. (3 МП)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152652/ios-html5-canvas-todataurl

У меня холст 950*950. 
Как обойти эту проблему ? Если сделать холст меньше, а затем на сервере его увеличить, то значительно потеряется качество.

Comment: На будущее: [`toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob), но, судя по поддержке, тебе не поможет...

Answer (score 4):

Попробуй вместо одного холста использовать несколько. Положи их так, чтобы они визуально образовывали единую картинку, а на сервере склеивай полное изображение из частей, расставляя их по нужным координатам.

Comment: У меня конструктор образов (из одежды). Такой вариант не подойдет, так как пользователи добавляют на холст одежду, и проделывают с ею различные манипуляции.  Если вовремя этих манипуляция, элемент одежды выйдет за границы одного из холстов, то на другом холсте , недостающую часть, будет достаточно сложно отобразить. 
https://itrend.com.ua/look/create

Comment: Но можно же отобразить ;)